# Having trouble increasing Dime maxRequestLength on my WSE 2.0 webservice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, wse

I tried everything I could find / think of.

I'm running a webservice on IIS6  WSE2.0 on dotNet Framework 3.5 ASP 1.1

I changed the service and client web.config adding both:

```
     <configSections>
<section  name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  <section name="microsoft.web.services2" type="Microsoft.Web.Services2.Configuration.WebServicesConfiguration, Microsoft.Web.Services2, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>

 <microsoft.web.services2> 
     <messaging>
       <maxRequestLength>8000</maxRequestLength>
     </messaging>
 </microsoft.web.services2>
```

and then

```
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8000" executionTimeout="1200" />
```

in the system.web section.

But still anything over 4MB fails with:  There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---> Maximum request length exceeded.

Comment: Did you know that WSE 2.0 is obsolete and extremely unsupported?

Comment: Yup, I also work for a company that doesn't like change. I inherited this and they want to keep it for now. Everything I read states that it should be able to clear well over 4MB. The fact that it has been around a while I'm hoping someone has run into this before.

Comment: Remind them it's not "been around a while" - it's badly obsolete. It's more obsolete than Windows XP.

Comment: If I remember right, you have to change the maxRequestLength, maxArrayLength, maxStringContentLength, maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize or else you will just have one issue after another.

Comment: You're right steve. I figured it out and got it working by adding the httpRuntime element like above to both the machine config and web config as well as "Enable Direct Metabase Edit on the IIS6 server then going to the corresponding xml to edit the ASPBuffering and attachment length there.